# my patch is not working for updating my data in my mern stack reshape in mongoose

Tags: mongoose, patch, mern

**ERROR ** Cannot PATCH /updatepost/60e*****************8a
in this project I'm unable to update my data in my mern stack project please help me in my project and I provided some of the code of my project and I just only want to update my project data using the database(Mongodb)

```
const express= require("express");
const mongoose=require("mongoose");
const router03=express.Router();
const Sch=require("../model/blogSchema");


router03.patch("/updating/:id",async (req,res)=>{
    const items={uname,utname,umyblog}=req.body;
    const id01=req.params.id;
    try{
      const updata = await Sch.findByIdAndUpdate({id:id01},{$set:items});
        res.send(updata);
    }catch(err){
         res.status(404).send(err);
    }
});

module.exports=router03;
```

model in project

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');


const blogSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    tname:{
        type:String,
        require:true,
    },
    myblog:{
        type:String,
        require:true,
    },
    name:{
        type:String,
        require:true,
    }
});

const UserInfo=mongoose.model('BLOGINFO',blogSchema);
module.exports=UserInfo;
```

front end in my project with updating and delete functionality

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import UpdateIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Update';
import axios from 'axios';

const Form=(props)=>{
    const [upost,setUpost]=useState({
        uname:'',
        utname:'',
        umyblog:'',
    });
    const [openit,setOpenit]=useState(false);

    const deleteBtn= async(id01)=>{
        try{
        const res=await axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/deletepost/${id01}`);
        const data=await res.send("done !!!!");
        console.log(data);
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        
    };
    const updateIt=()=>{
        setOpenit(!openit);
       
    }
    const handlingChange=(e)=>{
       const {name,value}=e.target;
       setUpost((items)=>{
        return{
            ...items,[name]:value,
        };
    });
    }

    const editing=async ()=>{
        const {uname,utname,umyblog}=upost;
        try {
            await axios.patch(`http://localhost:3001/updatepost/${props.id}`,{uname,utname,umyblog});
            setOpenit(!openit);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
      
}

return(
<>
<form method="GET">
    <div className="outercard01" >
    <h2 type="text" className="showname">{props.name}</h2>
    <h2 type="text" className="showtname">{props.tname}</h2>
    <p type="text" className="showblog">{props.myblog}</p>
    <div className="btns"><Button className="delbtn" method="POST" onClick={()=>{deleteBtn(props.id)}} ><DeleteIcon/></Button>
    <Button className="updatebtn" method="POST" onClick={updateIt}><UpdateIcon/></Button></div>
    </div>
    </form>
    {openit? 
    <>
     <form className="frms" method="PATCH">
        <input type="text" name="name" onChange={handlingChange} placeholder="Enter FirstName" className="name" value={upost.name}/>
        <input type="text" name="tname" onChange={handlingChange} placeholder="Topic Name" className="tname" value={upost.tname}/>
        <textarea type="text" name="myblog" onChange={handlingChange} placeholder="enter your blog" rows="" column="" className="bloggs" value={upost.myblog}/>
        <div className="btndiv">
        <button className="submitbtn" method="PATCH" onClick={editing}>Edit</button>
        </div>
        </form>
        </>
    :null}
</>
);


}
export default Form;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the patch  for updating the mongoose datq in the mongodb